# Forbidden region in particle-hole excitation spectrum?

Tags: condensed-matter

What is the reason behind getting a forbidden region in particle-hole excitation spectrum in 1-D case. For higher dimension I understood this spectrum as there is no forbidden region.

Comment: Are you talking about semiconductors/insulators or something else?